# Creating a couchdb view with keys based on sub-array element id's

Tags: javascript, database, couchdb

I have a document of the form:

```
{
_id: "...",
something: "...",
collection: [{collectionID: "id1", ...}, {collectionID: "id2", ...}]
}
```

I want to be able to retrieve documents based on `collectionID` values.  I tried making the following view:

```
function(doc) {
if(doc.collection) {
    for(let index; index < doc.collection.length; index++){
        emit(doc.collection[index].collectionID,doc);
    }
  }
}
```

But it was not a valid view and couchdb did not allow me to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript is too new :)

Change your “let” to “var”, or use a forEach loop instead.

CouchDB uses a fairly ancient version of Mozilla’s SpiderMonkey js engine for reasons.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize "let" was that new.  I knew of the need to use "ancient" javascript but thought "let" was ok.